# jQuery MouseOut triggers mouseEnter

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple mouse over code that appends `div`.

I also have a script for `mouseout` but it triggers on `mouseenter`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8ze0zuhL/)

```
<div class="topicaction">
<i class="fa fa-caret-down edit-topic-open" aria-hidden="true">Hover</i>                    
</div>

$( "body" ).on( "mouseenter", ".edit-topic-open", function() {
$(this).after('<div class="actipntrg"><span class="edit-topic" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#summernoteModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" data-value=""></i> Edit</span><span class="remove-topic"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" data-value=""></i> Remove </span><span class="cancel_a"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel</span></div>'); 

$( ".actipntrg" ).on( "mouseout" , function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "mouseout" to "mouseleave" and it should work. So you have this.

```
$( ".actipntrg" ).on( "mouseleave" , function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it is weird though because I tried it and it worked only when I moved my mouse out of the browser. But now it works

Comment: mouseout triggers when the mouse leaves the inner element. In this example, the mouse leaves .actipntrg and then enters .edit-topic. With mouseleave, it triggers when it leaves the element its bound to. So when you leave everything inside of .actipntrg. For a better explaination http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 1):

The code is

```
$( ".actipntrg" ).on( "mouseleave" , function() { $(this).remove(); }); });
```